# Cursor based approach vs set based approach

Tags: sql-server

I need to optimize a slow running stored procedure that uses a cursor-based approach to a set-based approach.

**In principle**, I have to compare records from a transient table (up to 300 records) against records from a "master table" (approx. half a million records and steadily growing). The matching is to be performed by comparing 20 varchar(11) columns of the two records. If at least 6 of these columns between the two records match (i.e. same data) that is considered to be a "sufficient match" and a record is to be created into a match table storing the IDs of the transient record and the master record, the total number of matches and the total number of mismatches.

*Note that the number of mismatches is not equal to the balance of 20 minus the number-of-matches. That's because if any of the columns in either of the two records contains a null, it is not counted as a match nor a mismatch; it is simply ignored. Thus the need to capture the two counts (business requirement).*

**The current implementation** uses an outer FAST_FORWARD cursor for the master table and an inner FAST_FORWARD cursor for the transient table. Within the inner cursor it has the following simple comparison logic applied to the 20 columns:

```
IF @newResults.data1 IS NOT NULL AND @results.data1 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @newResults.data1 = @results.data1
        SET @matchCount = @matchCount + 1
    ELSE                    
        SET @mismatchCount = @mismatchCount + 1
END
```

Then, if the total number of matching columns (i.e. `@matchCount`) is >= 6, a "match record" is written to a "match table" capturing the primary keys of the two records and the number of matches and mismatches.

**What I'm hoping to achieve:** rather than looping through the two nested cursors and process one record at a time, use a set-based implementation to process the above. One simple solution, I could think of, would be to do an:

```
INSERT INTO MatchingResults (ResultID, NewResultID, matchCount, mismatchCount)
SELECT (...) WHERE (...)
```

...and put the whole matching enchilada in the SELECT statement. But, this is the difficult part... Would anyone be able to give me some pointers here? Or suggest a better performing solution? Many thanks!

**Updated with table structures:**

```
--
-- Transient table:
--
table NewResults
(
   NewResultID int identity(1,1),
   Data1 varchar(11),
   Data2 varchar(11),
   ...
   Data20 varchar(11),
   SampleDate datetime
)
--
-- Master table:
--
table Results
(
   ResultID int identity(1,1),
   Data1 varchar(11),
   Data2 varchar(11),
   ...
   Data20 varchar(11),
   SampleDate datetime
)
--
-- Match table:
--
table MatchingResults
(
   ResultID int,
   NewResultID int,
   MatchCount int,
   MismatchCount int
)
```

Comment: Some table structure info would help you get an answer. Simplified/anonymised if need be.

Comment: Table structures added, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Surely you have one or more columns that constitute a primary key, and I am not referring to the primary key identity column that seems to be favored in SQL-Server databases. Do a join on those PK columns. As it is, you are doing the equivalent of a cross join, which would generate 500K by 300 records, then do 20 comparisons on each record (or is it 20 * 20 comparisons, as you compare each column with all of the others?)

Comment: Actually, in essence, I have to perform a Cartesian product as I need to compare each record from one table with each record from the other table using the 20 data fields and if any 6 of these fields match I create a match record and I have to store the number of fields matched as well as the number fields mismatched.

Comment: A cross join would help if you'd be matching a known number of key elements but I don't see how this could help when I have to deal with a minimum of any 6 out of 20 data fields.